# Mysql query optimize for searching records!

Tags: mysql, optimization, join

I am learning to use mysql.So, I got some problems.

I have three table :`users  movie  and  movie watching history(moviewh)`

the structure of `movie` table is:

```
movie_id[key]  movie_title
```

and `users` is:

```
user_id[key] user_name
```

and moviewh is:

```
user_id[key] movie_id[key] watching_date[key]
```

and my sql query is:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT m.movie_id,m.movie_name_cn FROM movie AS m
LEFT JOIN moviewh AS mwh  
ON m.movie_id = mwh.movie_id
WHERE date_format(mwh.watching_date,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2010-11-01' AND mwh.user_id = 1
```

[image]

so . how can I optimize the table and query ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing a left join if you are only interested in seeing what movies a user has watched on a particular date?

```
SELECT m.movie_id,m.movie_name_cn 
FROM movie AS m, moviewh AS mwh  
WHERE m.movie_id = mwh.movie_id
      AND date_format(mwh.watching_date,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2010-11-01' 
      AND mwh.user_id = 1
```

assuming of course that a user can't have watched movies that don't exist in your db ...

Comment: I found that your query still loop all records of moviewh !!The EXPLAIN reported the type is "ALL"

Comment: I am new to Mysql.I just want to learn something which I found!

Comment: Does `moviewh` have a composite index? If you have a three-column index on `(col1, col2, col3)`, you have indexed search capabilities on `(col1)`, `(col1, col2)`, and `(col1, col2, col3)`. So remove the where clause for `mwh.watching_date` and see...